# Make "NEW" folder in Photoshop script

Tags: photoshop, photoshop-script

A'm having trouble making a folder.

The scrip has its original folder like so: doc.exportDocument(File(doc.path+'/'+newName),ExportType.SAVEFORWEB,options);

but I'm trying to put the images in a named "NEW" folder within the image path like so" doc.path+'/New/'+newName
but no luck.

i tried making the folder right before the save like so:

```
var f = new Folder('doc.path+/New/');
   if (!f.exists)
  f.create();
```

but still the program tells me there is no such location.  How can i make that folder? 
thank you so much.
@l3ny

Comment: `(doc.path+'/New')` surely?

Answer (score 1):

```
var f = new Folder(doc.path + "/New/");
```

Comment: Guys this is what worked.
var doc  = activeDocument;  
var f = new Folder(doc.path+'/New folder');  
    if (!f.exists) {  
    f.create();  
    }